React/FluentUIv9 Popover won't work as provided in the docs
I'm using FluentUI v9 with the official docs from fluentui.dev.
I tried to use the Popover as described in the documentation, but my editor (and tsc) threw an error stating that the <Popover> element requires exactly two children (PopoverTrigger & PopoverSurface) or just one (PopoverSurface) with an custom target. There is sadly no such documentation about the custom target.
Doc example:
<Popover withArrow>
    <PopoverTrigger disableButtonEnhancement>
      <Button>Popover trigger</Button>
    </PopoverTrigger>

    <PopoverSurface tabIndex={-1}>
      <ExampleContent />
    </PopoverSurface>
  </Popover>

Example above has an Popover-Element with two childs, copy&paste of the code won't work.
My code:
<Popover withArrow open={this.state.openInvalidPopup}>
              <PopoverTrigger disableButtonEnhancement>
                <Button
                  size="medium"
                  onClick={() => this.onCreateBtnPress()}
                  appearance="primary"
                  icon={<FormNewFilled />}
                >
                  Create
                </Button>
              </PopoverTrigger>
              <PopoverSurface tabIndex={-1}>
                <div>
                  <span className={styles.h3FontSize}>
                    {"Text0"} <ClipboardErrorRegular />
                  </span>
                  <div>
                    {"Text1"}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </PopoverSurface>
           
        </Popover>

As you can see, i added a few extras, but i'm just using two childs as elements.
Error (Displayed in vscode):
Type '{ children: Element[]; open: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '{ appearance?: "brand" | "inverted" | undefined; children: Element | [Element, Element]; closeOnScroll?: boolean | undefined; defaultOpen?: boolean | undefined; ... 13 more ...; unstable_disableAutoFocus?: boolean | undefined; }'.
  Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
    Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'Element | [Element, Element]'.
      Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type '[Element, Element]'.
        Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2322)

The element "Popover" requires exact two elements. So there should be an array with [ReactElement, ReactElement] signature. For sure i could get that by using an predefined array, but is this really the way to go?
I managed to get it working with the dirty fix i mentioned:
<Popover open={this.state.openInvalidPopup}>
          {
            [
              <PopoverTrigger disableButtonEnhancement>
                <Button
                  size="medium"
                  onClick={() => this.onCreateBtnPress()}
                  appearance="primary"
                  icon={<FormNewFilled />}
                >
                  Create
                </Button>
              </PopoverTrigger>,
              <PopoverSurface tabIndex={-1}>
                <div>
                  <span className={styles.h3FontSize}>
                    {"Text0"} <ClipboardErrorRegular />
                  </span>
                  <div>
                    {"Text1"}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </PopoverSurface>,
            ] as [React.ReactElement, React.ReactElement]
          }
        </Popover>

..but is this really the way to go?
I’d appreciate any suggestions or better solutions for this.
reetings
